# Getting HTML content of a flask route from a different route

Tags: python, flask

Let's assume my code is like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    # Get HTML contents of route "/"
    return "test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now in the `test` function, I want to get the HTML content of the route `/` (which is `Hello World!`) programatically. Is there a way to do this ? Note that I don't want to use a library like `request` to do that because in my original use case both the route functions are authenticated and using  a library like `request` will just show "Access not allowed" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a function, you can call it.

```
def test():
    hello = hello_world()
```

However, if you have content you want to show in more than one handler, you should probably extract it into a separate function that you can call from both routes.